# Iterate over all unique two-element combinations

Tags: java, guava

I need to iterate over all combinations of two elements: in a set [1,2,3,4] I want to iterate over [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]. Is there an existing tool to do so?

```
// Not what I need, works wrong!
for (Object o1 : set) {
  for (Object o2 : set) {
    if (o1 == o2) continue;
    ...
  }
}
```

This code would do twice more operations than needed, because each object will be visited in both loops.

It is trivial to write my own method for that, I just don't want to invent the wheel. I'd expect to find this in Guava or Collections API, but didn't find such functionality.

Comment: First of all, you should use `o1.equals(o2)` instead of `o1 == o2`, unless you're actually working with primitives.

Comment: @Cedric_Reichenbach No. That is a set, there can't be two elements that equal each other. == is enough here.

Comment: You will always need to iterate over both the sets to find those combinations. Even if you get another api internal logic will have same complexity.

Comment: it should be `if(o1>=o2) continue;` to get the output you said

Comment: @Lokesh I don't care about complexity, I care about verbosity.

Comment: @Math No, o1 and o2 are not indices, those are objects. Besides you can't compare objects with `>=`.

Comment: @Susei you can if you implement the Comparable interface. Anyway, your code doesn't output what you stated it does.

Comment: @Math Fine, but why would I compare objects for my task in the first place? That has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Susei it may lead people to the wrong answer, as the correct output for the code you posted is `(1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 1) (2, 3) (2, 4) (3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 4) (4, 1) (4, 2) (4, 3)`. Basically there is an inconsistence in the question.

Comment: @Math Yes, that's why in the next sentence I explain why that code is wrong for my task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/
Simple combinations section illustrates usage of this utility.
Combinations with 2 elements will produce what you wanted.

```
    // Create the initial vector
    ICombinatoricsVector<String> initialVector = Factory.createVector(
      new String[] { "red", "black", "white", "green", "blue" } );

   // Create a simple combination generator to generate 3-combinations of the initial vector
   Generator<String> gen = Factory.createSimpleCombinationGenerator(initialVector, 3);

   // Print all possible combinations
   for (ICombinatoricsVector<String> combination : gen) {
      System.out.println(combination);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `continue` by `break` nearly does what you want: It produces no swapped pairs. It also halves the overhead (which you don't care about).

You only need to swap the names of `o1` and `o2` to get exactly the pairs you want.

---

As pointed out in a comment, there's no iteration order guarantee for `Set`s. So to be sure, convert the `Set` to a `List` beforehand. For big sets, this is much cheaper than the pairing itself (`O(n)` vs `O(n*n)`).

Comment: A very nice solution! Though I'm not sure if any existing Set implementation would be iterated in the same order in these two loops (which is a necessary condition for this to work), but still.

Comment: @Susei: All Iterables I've ever seen do iterate in a fixed order. It can change between implementations (and this surely happened with JDK9 `HashSet`), but the implementors strive not to do it. But you're right, there's no such guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what Set are you going to use but if it has a random access, that is if you can explicitly ask for a member in position `i`, then you can use a double `for` with the second iterator gradually increasing:
e.g.

```
for(i = 0; i < Set1_size; i++)
 for(j = i; j < Set1_size; i++)
{ o1.get(i).equals(o2); }
```

This way you are looping through only ~half (actually half + your main diagonal) the previous comparisons.

Comment: Use `set.size()`. And there's only one set, not two. `j++` you meant in the second `for`, right?

Comment: You mix up Set and Collection. Set doesn't have random access by definition. You're talking about a List. But the logic is fine, I can translate a Set to an ad-hoc List and loop over that. Though I'd still look for an existing tool with a meaningful name instead of writing cycles. Like `Iterable<Pair<Object, Object>> Sets.allCombinationsOf(set, 2)`

Comment: With your implementation you would need to convert the set to an array first, because there is no such thing as `get`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yup, that's exaclty what I meant with "translate a Set to an ad-hoc List".

Comment: Yes in the second for loop it should have been `j++`